# Dormant Grape Cutting Callus Timeline

Tags: propagation, cuttings, grape-vine

I’m currently trying to propagate grape vines using dormant cuttings. I understand that these cuttings are supposed to callus and form roots before the buds break. I am accomplishing this by using bottom heat and rooting hormone.

If I get the cuttings to root but it’s still to early for planting (freezing and snowy), can I remove the bottom heat and reintroduce the cuttings to the cold environment until spring? Would this kill the new roots? Or should I bundle the cuttings and place the roots in saw dust and keep them in the fridge? Otherwise, what would happen if I left the bottom heat as is until spring? Would the cutting exhaust itself on growing roots?